# crond not loading /etc/pam.d/crond config

Tags: cron, pam

I have this PAM config in /etc/pam.d/crond:

```
auth required pam_env.so user_readenv=1
```

And this `.pam_environment` file:

```
_APP_PASSWORD DEFAULT=foo
```

And this test cronjob:

```
*/1 * * * * root env 2&>1 | logger -t debug_cron
```

I'm watching the logs with `journalctl -f -t debug_cron` and every minute or so several lines appear in the console with the vars, and I see the usual `HOME`, `SHELL`, etc., but I don't see the one I set in `.pam_environment`. Why is this? How can I make this work?

The server is running Fedora 34 64 bit.

Comment: Due to the way PAM works it is helpful to see the entire file. For example, if this **required** comes *after* a successful **sufficient**, it will not execute.

Comment: What you see is the entire PAM file, it just has that one line